# File monitoring

Tags: windows, file, logging, filesystems

my goal is to track the usage of every internal file of my software.

Example:

- My program is located in C:\myprogram and has inside 12 subfolders and 4 files, every subfolder has subfolders and files. Lets' make it simple and say under the "myprogram" folder there are 100 files i'd like to track (executable programs who call other files inside the same folder structure).
- Which info do I want to know? Who (system user) used / accessed the file  and at hat time.

I am sure some of the files are unused and i'm migrating to a new technology so i don't want to rewrite programs that are not used. So what I'm doing here is tracking usage frequency to decide wether to rewrite or not all the procedures.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What does "executable programs who call other files inside the same folder structure" mean? Reading a file or running it as a process?

Comment: Just accessing the files, using them. It's all running under the same process (myprog.exe) and the .exe is calling other compiled files.

Comment: Make sure access times are turned on in the OS and filesystem and then use the directory monitor functions.